# Creating Polyline feature from points using for loop in Python: No error but does not create the features either

Tags: python, shapefile, arcpy

I am new to Python and trying to create a Polyline feature from Lat longs in a text file. Using answers to similar questions, below is the code I came up with. It doesn't throw an error but doesn't create polyline feature either. The LatLongs.txt contains three columns 1) unique identifier, 2) Latitude, 3) Longitude. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=1
array = arcpy.Array()

outFolder=r'C:\Temp'
fc = 'PolylineCSV.shp'
spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=outFolder, out_name=fc, 
                                   geometry_type='POLYLINE', 
                                   spatial_reference=spatRef)

featureList = []
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor("C:\\Temp\\PolylineCSV.shp")
feat = cursor.newRow()

coordinateList="C:\\Temp\\LatLongs.txt"
with open(coordinateList) as f:
    for line in f:           
        SplitLine = line.split(',') 
        x = float(SplitLine[2]) #Get longitude
        y = float(SplitLine[1]) #Get latitude
        point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
        array.add(point)
        try:
            nextline=next(f)
            SplitnextLine = nextline.split(',')
            x = float(SplitnextLine[2])
            y = float(SplitnextLine[1])
            point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
            array.add(point)
            polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)                     
            array.removeAll()
            # Append to the list of Polyline objects
            featureList.append(polyline)
            feat.shape = polyline
            # Insert the feature
            cursor.insertRow(feat)
        except StopIteration as e:
            print("error handled")
del feat
del cursor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ArcGIS for Desktop**

Your issue is *most likely* this line: `feat.shape = polyline`. `feat` has no `shape` property. You may use [`feat.setValue("shape", polyline)`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/insertcursor.htm). Here is an example based on your code (but without looping through a CSV file):

```py
import os
import arcpy

output_folder = r"c:\temp"
output_file = "trips.shp"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
    output_folder, output_file, "POLYLINE", spatial_reference=sr)

cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(os.path.join(output_folder, output_file))

array = arcpy.Array()

array.add(arcpy.Point(8.541, 47.374))
array.add(arcpy.Point(-63.716, 44.867))

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array, spatial_reference=sr)

feature = cursor.newRow()

# set the geometry
feature.setValue("shape", polyline)

cursor.insertRow(feature)

del cursor
```

It looks like you are using ArcGIS for Desktop. If you are using 10.1 or newer, then you should use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` instead `arcpy.InsertCursor`.

> [`arcpy.InsertCursor`] was superceded by `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` at ArcGIS 10.1. For faster performance, use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/data-access-using-cursors.htm

---

**ArcGIS Pro**

**If** I understand your code correctly, then every two points (lines) in your CSV file should be a line. Here are two working examples:

```py
import os
import csv
import arcpy, arcpy.da, arcpy.management
```

Use [`arcpy.da.InsertCursor`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm):

```py
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

output_folder = r"c:\temp"
output_file_name = "trips.shp"

input_file = r"d:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data\trips.csv"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

output_feature_class = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
    output_folder, output_file_name, geometry_type="POLYLINE", spatial_reference=sr)

with open(input_file) as csv_file, \
        arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_feature_class, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)  # skip header line

    for row in reader:
        
        first_point = arcpy.Point(row[2], row[3])

        next_row = next(reader, None)

        if next_row:

            second_point = arcpy.Point(next_row[2], next_row[3])

            line = arcpy.Polyline(
                arcpy.Array([first_point, second_point]), spatial_reference=sr)

            cursor.insertRow([line])
```

Or, use [`arcpy.management.CopyFeatures`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm):

```py
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_file = r"d:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data\trips.csv"
output_file = r"c:\temp\trips.shp"

features = []

with open(input_file) as csv_file:

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)  # skip header line

    for row in reader:
        
        first_point = arcpy.Point(row[2], row[3])

        next_row = next(reader, None)

        if next_row:

            second_point = arcpy.Point(next_row[2], next_row[3])

            line = arcpy.Polyline(
                arcpy.Array([first_point, second_point]), spatial_reference=sr)

            features.append(line)

arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(features, output_file)
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding the shape fixed it. Also added the spatial reference with the Polyline function to make it work.

Comment: You are welcome. I just added the argument for the spatial reference in the first code example for completeness in my answer too.